# Difference between "or" and "||"

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between

```
if ( a or b or c ) {
```

...and...

```
if ( a || b || c ) {
```

...and more in general between the two operators, even in terms of precedence ?

Comment: There is no difference in any respect. They are equivalent.

Comment: Omg, 10 years of C++ experience and I didn't know they ('or', 'and' etc) existed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the stylistic sense that makes a lot of seasoned programmers think "Huh, has someone suddenly started writing Pascal?", there is no functional difference.

The purpose of these alternative names is to allow people living in, say, Sweden or Germany, to use a standard Local variant of ASCII, where `|` is  `ö`.

Since the introduction of Unicode and extended ASCII, this need has pretty much disappeared, since nationalized character sets don't have to "steal" less commonly used characters to produce their national "special" characters.

Comment: Back in university, I saw a guy having a macro library making the C++ code looking almost exactly like pascal. Including `begin` and `end`.

Comment: I did not understand your second paragraph - to my knowledge `ö` does not exist in the danish ASCII table and certainly not on a danish keyboard. On a danish keyboard the pipe character `|` is located in first row left of `←Backspace` and over `Å` whereas on a US keyboard pipe is - as you all know - located below `←Backspace`.

Comment: ASCII is ASCII, and there are no variants. Maybe you meant codepages, but those vary only in the region beyond ASCII, i.e. character values from 128 through 255. The `|` and `&` characters are in ASCII and therefore in any codepage. What is different in other countries is the keyboard layout, and when those special characters might be hard to access, `or`, `and` etc. come in.

Comment: Right, I started out with Denmark/Danish, and then realized I couldn't write what I wanted without mucking about with character maps, and changed to Swedish/Danish. I'm also not talking about the 8-bit character set that we all know these days, but the 7-bit variant that is ASCII, and its localized variants that REPLACE some of the unusual characters in the ASCII character set to allow the umlauted characters to be used. There's a good example here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#7-bit. 

And yes, I doubt that & ever was "replaced with something else", but once you start with | ...

Comment: Note that these things were still used on for example VAX-systems in the early 1990's, a fair while after the PC was introduced, with it's codepages and 8-bit character set. But it really didn't come in until well after PC's were introduced.

Answer (score 2):

*edited* You can overload `operator or`.

They are the same.

See [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators).

If you overload `operator or` for a type, you can't then overload `operator||` for the same type as the compiler will consider them to be the same function.

This error comes from the following code:

```
> prog.cpp: In function ‘bool operator||(Type, Type)’:
> prog.cpp:8:6: error: redefinition of ‘bool operator||(Type, Type)’
> prog.cpp:4:6: error: ‘bool operator||(Type, Type)’ previously defined here
```

On [ideaone](http://ideone.com/ZdMvR1):

```
class Type {}
};

bool operator or(Type lhs, Type rhs) {
    return true;
}

bool operator ||(Type lhs, Type rhs) {
    return false;
}

int main() {
    Type a;
    Type b;
    a or b;
    a || b;
}
```

Comment: While you can not overload `or` to mean a different thing than `||` you can overload `||` and using `or` will use that too.

Comment: You can overload it, but it's then named `operator or`.

Answer (score 1):

As per ISO14882:2011(e) 2.6-2 (Table 2) `or` is an alternative token for `||`, and as such has exactly the same meaning:

> In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the
>   same, respectively, as its primary token,except for its spelling.

Often compilers implement them as `#define or ||` or the internal equivalent.

Same for `and`, `bitor`, `xor`, `compl`, `bitand`, `and_eq`, `or_eq`, `xor_eq`, `not` and `not_eq`.

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the other answers, the two are meant to be the same and thus exchangeable. But there is one big difference: MSVC, C++ Builder and maybe other compilers as well do not support `or` without including a special header. That makes using `or` a portability obstacle.